# Puppet to Chef (Git pull with RSA key on Windows)

Tags: git, chef-infra, puppet

I'm new to Chef and been trying to convert this code from Puppet to Chef.. Can anyone out there help?

```
vcsrepo { "C:\ProgramData\checks":
    ensure => latest,
    provider => 'git',
    source => "git@domain.org:ops/checks.git",
    identity => "C:/ProgramData/id_rsa",
    notify => Service["Service_Agent"],
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`poise-git` didn't work.

Here's what worked:
Edit C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh\ssh_config

Add the path for the SSH key:

```
Host SERVER_FQDN
  IdentityFile C:\path\id_rsa
```

Use this recipe:

```
git 'C:\\destination\\here' do
   repository 'git@domain.org:name.git'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't directly available in Chef core, specifically using an SSH key with a `git` resource. Check out the `poise-git` cookbook and `poise_git` resource which adds this.

Comment: coderanger again to the rescue! Thanks mate. Quick question, when I install such a cookbook, do I also need to install the dependencies? (found in the dependencies tab: poise-languages & poise)

Comment: Yes. Berks handles this automatically for you though.